# Coverage is not showing up in Sonar(Python) code's reporting

Tags: python, maven, sonarqube, code-coverage

I'm currently having a hard a time trying to make the coverage appear,

The coverage file (cobertura xml) is generated properly on the specified `target` directory, then and have it specified on `sonar.python.coverage.reportPath` (which based from my parent pom file). The top level is the parent pom and different directories(packages).

This is how the pom properties of the `module-test`'s pom looks like

```
<sonar.inclusions>**/python/*/*.py</sonar.inclusions>
<sonar.exclusions>**/python/*/__init__.py</sonar.exclusions>
<sonar.language>py</sonar.language>
<sonar.python.coverage.reportPath>target/cov-report/cov-report.xml</sonar.python.coverage.reportPath>
```

Could it be because the inclusions prevent it from being added? 
I currently have it set up so that sonar only analyzes our essential files.

This is the project structure:

```
module-a
    src
        python
    target  
module-b
    src
       python
    target  
module-c
    src
       python
    target  
module-test
    src
       python
           functionA
           functionB
       unit_test.py
    target
        cov-report
            cov-report.xml
    pom.xml
pom.xml


[WARNING] JUnit report directory not found at 
/home/jenkins/workspace/master-ASDASKDOKAOK/module-test/sonar-reports
[INFO] Sensor Swift Surefire Sensor (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] Sensor SCM Sensor
[INFO] Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=1ms
[INFO] Sensor Python Squid Sensor
[INFO] Python unit test coverage
[INFO] Parsing report '/home/jenkins/workspace/master-ASDASKDOKAOK/module-test/target/cov-report/cov-report.xml'
[INFO] Python integration test coverage
[INFO] Python overall test coverage
[INFO] Sensor Python Squid Sensor (done) | time=1311ms
[INFO] Sensor XmlFileSensor
[INFO] Sensor XmlFileSensor (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files
[INFO] Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=9ms
[INFO] Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
[INFO] Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer
[INFO] DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for py
[INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=52ms
```

Sonar version is  sonar-python-plugin-1.8.0.1496

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant portion from the analysis log and possibly also your exclusions and your project structure.

Comment: Hi @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam 

will do

Comment: I added the project structure, where do I find the analysis log? @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam

Comment: By analysis logs I mean what's output to ... console, or jenkins log, or ...?, when you analyze

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Hello, sorry for the late reply. I updated my question.

Comment: What version of SonarPython are you using? (Depending on your version, you'll find it either in Administration > System > Update Center, or Administration > Marketplace)

Comment: Sonar version is `sonar-python-plugin-1.8.0.1496`  @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam

Comment: I've done some changes so I updated the information from my question. @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam

Comment: Is the code that's covered by your tests in the same module as the tests? From your structure diagram, I suspect not, and believe that that's probably your problem.

Comment: So the test should be in the same module? I updated my structure diagram to provide more details. `module-test` is only testing `module-test` at the moment as well.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tag you from my response above. @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam